# how to add nodes to an existing graph in networkx?

Tags: python, graph, beautifulsoup, nodes, networkx

Consider this code:

```
 G = nx.DiGraph()
 H=nx.path_graph(counter+1)
 G.add_nodes_from(H)
 labels = dict([ x for x in enumerate(idvalue) ])
 l =len(idvalue)
 labels[l]=userid
 for node in H:
     G.add_edge(node,l)
 pos=nx.spring_layout(G)
 nx.draw(G, pos=pos, node_color='g', node_size=20, with_labels=False)
 nx.draw_networkx_labels(G,pos,labels,font_size=16)
 plt.show()
```

Here, I'm extracting `userid` & `idvalue` from a URL using beautiful soup and these two values change as I iterate over a set of URLs. How to maintain one graph and add nodes as and when I extract content?

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure it's really creating multiple graphs?  Or is it plotting the same graph with a different appearance multiple times?  Each time you draw it, you're creating a new (somewhat) random set of node positions and redrawing.  So each drawing will be different.

Answer (score 0):

you're already using `add_edge()` which adds the nodes as well if they don't exist.
if you want to add just a node with no edges attached you can use [`add_node()`](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.MultiGraph.add_node.html)

Comment: The code that I posted creates multiple graphs but I want just one that holds ALL the nodes. 'Counter' determines the number of nodes that goes into the graph and this value is calculated during every iteration..

Comment: the code you posted does not undergo any iterations. if it is the body of some loop thats not posted, just create the graph once outside the loop instead of creating a new instance each iteration.

Comment: I tired that too, it still creates multiple graphs

Comment: You'll have to show more code if this doesn't solve your problem.  yurib's answer is correct for the question you've posed.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not that it's creating multiple graphs.  Instead it's that you're plotting the same graph multiple times, and each time it looks different.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G=nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edge(1,2)
labels = {1:1, 2:2}
for ctr in range(4):
    pos=nx.spring_layout(G)
    nx.draw(G, pos=pos, node_color='g', node_size=20, with_labels=True)
    nx.draw_networkx_labels(G,pos,labels,font_size=16)
    plt.savefig('fig'+str(ctr)+'.png')
```

You should see that it probably looks different each time it plots.  That's because by default spring_layout has randomness built in.  Since it's plotting in the same figure each time, it will look like you're getting lots of different graphs (note, how it handles the replotting if you do this in an interactive environment depends somewhat on that environment).  You can fix this by adding `plt.clf()` before the plotting.

here's my first and last figures:

[image] [image]